# Is there a way to force every element of a (multiset_of<int>,multiset_of<int>) boost::bimap to be unique?

Tags: c++, boost, bimap, boost-bimap

I have a multi set Bimap that looks like:

```
6 <--> 71
6 <--> 71
6 <--> 71
8 <--> 71
8 <--> 71
10 <--> 71
10 <--> 74
```

element = left key + right key, or a row in the above block

I would like to remove the elements where the lines are equivalent to another line, for example, I would like to remove two lots of the 6 <--> 71. Essentially, **every bimap element must be unique**. The left and right keys must be multi sets for my use-case. **I would also like to do this post creating the bimap**. Is there an inbuilt function that requires every element to be unique? If this isn't the case, does anyone know a good way to do this?

The minimal code I am using is as follows:

```
  typedef boost::bimap<boost::bimaps::multiset_of<int>,
                       boost::bimaps::multiset_of<int>> bimap;
  bimap bm;
//fill with elements from two vectors
//vectors have the same size by definition
  for(int j = 0; j < matching1.size(); j++){
    bm.insert({matching1[j],matching2[j]});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use the [third parameter of `bimap`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/the_collection_of_relations_type.html) to constrain the whole collection.

```
typedef boost::bimap<boost::bimaps::multiset_of<int>,
                     boost::bimaps::multiset_of<int>,
                     boost::bimaps::set_of_relation<>
                    > bimap;
```

If you want to first construct a bimap with duplicate pairs, then use your original definition. You can initialise the second bimap from the first, e.g.

```
typedef boost::bimap<boost::bimaps::multiset_of<int>,
                     boost::bimaps::multiset_of<int>
                    > bimap;

typedef boost::bimap<boost::bimaps::multiset_of<int>,
                     boost::bimaps::multiset_of<int>,
                     boost::bimaps::set_of_relation<>
                    > unique_bimap;

bimap data = { ... };
unique_bimap uniqued_data { data.begin(), data.end() };
```

Comment: Thank you! This did exactly what I wanted